# How to create variables to loop over files and emerge in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a DataFrame with data for Tennis matches of a specific player 'Lenny Hampel'. For this I downloaded a lot of .json files with data for of his matches - all in all there are around 100 files. As it is a json file i need to convert every single file into a dict, to get it into the dataframe in the end. Finally I need to concatenate each file to the dataframe. I could hard-code it, however it is kind of silly I think, but I could not find a proper way to iterate trough this.

Could you help me understand how I could create a loop or smth else in order to code it the smart way?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import json
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd
import pprint

with open('lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (1).json') as json_file:
    lennymatch1 = json.load(json_file)

player = [item 
          for item in lennymatch1["stats"] 
          if item["player_fullname"] == "Lenny Hampel"]

with open('lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (2).json') as json_file:
    lennymatch2 = json.load(json_file)

player2 = [item 
          for item in lennymatch2["stats"] 
          if item["player_fullname"] == "Lenny Hampel"]

with open('lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (3).json') as json_file:
    lennymatch3 = json.load(json_file)

player33 = [item 
          for item in lennymatch3["stats"] 
          if item["player_fullname"] == "Lenny Hampel"]


with open('lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (4).json') as json_file:
    lennymatch4 = json.load(json_file)

player4 = [item 
          for item in lennymatch4["stats"] 
          if item["player_fullname"] == "Lenny Hampel"]


tabelle1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player)
tabelle2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player2)
tabelle3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player33)
tabelle4 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player4)

tennisstats = [tabelle1, tabelle2, tabelle3, tabelle4]

result = pd.concat(tennisstats)
result
```

Comment: Please get rid of the screenshot and post your code as formatted text

Comment: updated @roganjosh

Comment: `for filename in ["lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (1).json", "lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (2).json", ...]: ... open(filename) ...`

Comment: if filenames are similar but they have different number then maybe `for number in range(1, 101): filename = "lenny/2016/lenny2016_match ({}).json".format(number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems so basic knowledge that I don't understand why you ask for this.

```
# --- before loop ---

tennisstats = []

# --- loop ---

for filename in ["lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (1).json", "lenny/2016/lenny2016_match (2).json"]: 

    with open(filename) as json_file:
         lennymatch = json.load(json_file)

    player = [item 
         for item in lennymatch["stats"] 
         if item["player_fullname"] == "Lenny Hampel"]

    tabele = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player)

    tennisstats.append(tabele)

# --- after loop ---

result = pd.concat(tennisstats)
```

---

If filenames are similar and they have only different number

```
for number in range(1, 101):

    filename = f"lenny/2016/lenny2016_match ({number}).json"

    with open(filename) as json_file:
```

and rest is the same as in first version.

---

If all files are in the same folder then maybe you should use `os.listdir()`

```
directory = "lenny/2016/"

for name in os.listdir(directory):

    filename = directory + name

    with open(filename) as json_file:
```

and rest is the same as in first version.